# Swap specific <key,value> set in HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, hashmap, mapping

I work with a mapping of `<String,Integer>`, Name (unique) and grade.
I sorted so the highest grade comes first (with its key value).
However in the case that two grades are the same, I need them to be printed in Alphabetical order.

So far I got this, which sorts by value, in descending order:

```
public  <String, Integer extends Comparable<? super Integer>> Map<String, Integer> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());



    //actually need descending order, so use comparator to change from natural ordering
    Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
    list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue(comparator));


    Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return results;
}
```

The I tried to maybe work by copying to ArrayList, although I feel in a dead end:

```
   List<String> listnames = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String names :  result.keySet()){
        listnames.add(names);
    }
    List<Integer> listgrades = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Integer grades :  result.values()){
        listgrades.add(grades);
    }


for (int i = 0 ; i<result.size() ; i ++){
    if(listgrades.get(i).equals(listgrades.get(i+1))){
        result.get(listgrades.);
        //.....

    }
}
```

Any helps/tips appreciated!

Comment: Not really related to main question but by writing `public  <String, Integer extends Comparable<? super Integer>> Map<String, Integer> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> map) {` you are declaring *generic types* with names `String` and `Integer` which means they don't represent `java.lang.String` or `java.lang.Integer`. Are you sure you need such generic types (if yes then at least change their names to something less confusing like `KeyType` or  better `K` and `ValueType` or `V`).

Answer (score 0):

You are able to sort by both properties simultaneously:

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue);
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> comparator2 = comparator.reversed(); // Here sort the grade in reversed order (highest come first)
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(comparator2.thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
                  .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                           (v1, v2) -> v2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

You're making the things more complicated by introduce a `Map`.

You can do the same thing with your `List<Student>` where `Student {name; grade}`

Comment: Why did you duplicate your answer (you deleted [original one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50432557), but it still exist in system and can be seen by users with 10k or more reputation)? If it was to attract OP's attention then please don't do it. OP can see that answer was updated by noticing the "reload" bar at top of the answer.

Comment: It's show a banner like `deleted post by original user` and somehow I can't click through it

Comment: Strange since you are author system should let you see that post. Anyway this is what I am referring as duplicating your answer: https://imgur.com/FDZr48e (you should also see it here). Multiple answers by same author are allowed to share *different solutions* so people could vote on them separately. So please don't abuse the system just for OP attention.

Comment: Ya, when I refresh I see my deleted post. But now I can't delete the old one. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

It will help based on your statements to define some rudimentary classes to encompass what you are trying to achieve.

Then  define a custom comparator class to perform your custom sort.

```
class Student
{
    String name;
    int grade;

    // Constructor
    public Student(String name, int grade)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    // Used to print student details in main()
    public String toString()
    {
        return ""+String.format("%-10s - %3d",this.name, this.grade); 
    }
}

class SortbyGradedescNameAsc implements Comparator<Student>
{
    // Used for sorting in 
    // Descending order of grade, then 
    // Ascending order of Name 
    public int compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
        int result = b.grade - a.grade;
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }else{
            return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
        }
    }
}

public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){

        ArrayList<Student> ar = new ArrayList<Student>();
        ar.add(new Student( "bob", 60));
        ar.add(new Student( "ted", 70));
        ar.add(new Student( "gord", 80));
        ar.add(new Student( "fred", 90));
        ar.add(new Student( "sam", 70));
        ar.add(new Student( "maggie", 70));
        ar.add(new Student( "alfred", 50));
        ar.add(new Student( "adam", 50));

        System.out.println("-- Unsorted --");
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(ar.get(i));

        Comparator c = new SortbyGradedescNameAsc();
        Collections.sort(ar, c);

        System.out.println(" -- grade sorted descending then name sorted ascending --");
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(ar.get(i));

     }
}
```

-- Output below --

```
-- Unsorted --
bob        -  60
ted        -  70
gord       -  80
fred       -  90
sam        -  70
maggie     -  70
alfred     -  50
adam       -  50
-- grade sorted Descending then name sorted Ascending --
fred       -  90
gord       -  80
maggie     -  70
sam        -  70
ted        -  70
bob        -  60
adam       -  50
alfred     -  50
```